# MySQL - Find the closest previous date and update matching records from another table

Tags: mysql

I'm looking to find the closest previous sdt from returndate and get the associated id_reference by idno and update the id_reference in @sampleship table. id_reference is a unique number combinateion of idno and returndate.

I have a query that I made in TSQL, any help to convert this to mySQL to fit in my requirements or is there any other alternative approach.

I'm using MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE

Below is a sample DDL and desired result. Thank you in advance.

```
create table sampleReturns(idno varchar(35),id varchar(35), returndate 
datetime, id_reference varchar(60))      
insert into sampleReturns (idno,id, returndate, id_reference ) 
values ('12345670','123456PH','2022-04-26 00:00:00','2022-04-26 00:00:0012345670'),
('12345678','123456AB','022-01-31 00:00:00',2022-01-31 00:00:0012345678'),
('12345678','123456AB','2022-02-18 00:00:00','2022-02-18 00:00:0012345678'),
('12345678','123456AB','2022-05-25 00:00:00','2022-05-25 00:00:0012345678'),
('12345650','123456TW','2022-03-01 00:00:00','2022-03-01 00:00:0012345650'),
('22345688','223456PK','2022-01-21 00:00:00','2022-01-21 00:00:0022345688'),
('22345688','223456PK','2022-03-08 00:00:00','2022-03-08 00:00:0022345688')


create table @sampleship table(idno varchar(35),id varchar(35), sdt datetime, id_reference varchar(60))      
insert into @sampleship table (idno,into, sdt, id_reference ) 
values ('12345670','123456PH','2020-11-26 00:00:00',NULL),           
('12345670','123456PH','2022-04-23 00:00:00',NULL),          
('12345670','123456PH','2022-07-25 00:00:00',NULL),          
('12345678','123456AB','2022-01-31 00:00:00',NULL),          
('12345678','123456AB','2022-08-25 00:00:00',NULL),           
('12345678','123456AB','2022-02-22 00:00:00',NULL),           
('12345650','123456TW','2022-02-25 00:00:00',NULL),           
('22345688','223456PK','2022-01-31 00:00:00',NULL),           
('22345688','223456PK','2022-05-25 00:00:00',NULL)
```

Desired result: @sampleship table

| idno | id | sdt | id_reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345670 | 123456PH | 2020-11-26 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 12345670 | 123456PH | 2022-04-23 00:00:00 | 2022-04-26 00:00:0012345670 |
| 12345670 | 123456PH | 2022-07-25 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 12345678 | 123456AB | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 2022-02-18 00:00:0012345678 |
| 12345678 | 123456AB | 2022-08-25 00:00:00 | 2022-05-25 00:00:0012345678 |
| 12345678 | 123456AB | 2022-02-22 00:00:00 | NULL |
| 12345650 | 123456TW | 2022-02-25 00:00:00 | 2022-03-01 00:00:0012345650 |
| 22345688 | 223456PK | 2022-01-31 00:00:00 | 2022-03-08 00:00:0022345688 |
| 22345688 | 223456PK | 2022-05-25 00:00:00 | NULL |

```
;with cte_sampleReturns  as 
(
select 
idno,
returndate,
LEAD(returndate,1) over(partition by idno order by returndate,) as lead_returndate,
id_reference
from @sampleReturns  
)
update T set id_reference=T1.id_reference 
from @sampleship T
inner join cte_sampleReturns T1 on T.idno=T1.idno and ((T.sdt>=T1.returndate and 
T1.lead_returndate, is null) 
      OR (T.sdt>=T1.returndate and T.sdt<T1.lead_returndate, and T1.lead_returndate, is not 
null))
```

Thanks

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. *Below is a sample DDL* Must be CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO. *Find the closest previous date and update matching records from another table* Use LATERAL JOIN or correlated subquery (with ORDER BY + LIMIT). PS. Not related to Workbench - tag removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logically I suppose a return can only happen after a shipment so it follows that a return BETWEEN 2 shipments belongs to the earliest of the 2 shipment dates. If the shipment table terminates without finding a next shipment (ie null) then substituting now() could help. In mysql multi table update syntax applies and there is no need for a cte

```
update shipped
join
(
select s1.*,r.id_reference ridref
from 
(select s.*, 
  case when lead(sdt) over (partition by idno,id order by sdt) is null then now()
  else      lead(sdt) over (partition by idno,id order by sdt)
  end nextsdt
from shipped s
) s1
left join returns r on r.idno = s1.idno and r.id = s1.id and r.returndate between s1.sdt and s1.nextsdt

#order by s1.idno,s1.id,s1.sdt

) x
on x.idno = shipped.idno and x.id = shipped.id and x.sdt = shipped.sdt
set shipped.id_reference = x.ridref;
```

Or if you are on a version prior to 8.0

```
update shipped
join
(
select s1.*, #sdt ,
        case when 
                (select sdt
                from shipped s2 
                where s2.idno = s1.idno and s2.id = s1.id and s2.sdt > s1.sdt order by s2.sdt asc limit 1) 
                is null then 
                    now()
            else
                (select sdt
                from shipped s2 
                where s2.idno = s1.idno and s2.id = s1.id and s2.sdt > s1.sdt order by s2.sdt asc limit 1) 
            end
            nextstd ,
            r.id_reference newidref
from shipped s1
left join returns r on r.idno = s1.idno and r.id = s1.id and r.returndate between s1.sdt and
            case when 
                    (select sdt 
                    from shipped s2 
                    where s2.idno = s1.idno and s2.id = s1.id and s2.sdt > s1.sdt order by s2.sdt asc limit 1) 
                    is null then 
                            now()
                else
                    (select sdt
                    from shipped s2 
                    where s2.idno = s1.idno and s2.id = s1.id and s2.sdt > s1.sdt order by s2.sdt asc limit 1) 
            end
order by idno,id,sdt
) x
on x.idno = shipped.idno and x.id = shipped.id and x.sdt = shipped.sdt
set shipped.id_reference = newidref
;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried to execute the query and I'm encountering an error. I think the Lead function is not working on MySQL. Maybe I have an outdated  version of MySQL. Is there any other approached of not using the Lead function.

Comment: See edit and as requested by AKINA add the version you are on to your question - select version();

Comment: Thank you @P.Salmon,  I will try this code in my actual data.